# How do I can I access elements in json file (API) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to display all names in this JSON file,

https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/41P1_UhSI

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       
        const api_url = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/41P1_UhSI'; 
        async function getAPI() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(Object.values(data.name)); //or console.log(data.name);
        }
        getAPI();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error: "undefined" when I run this code.

Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` isn't an object with a `name` property, so `name` is undefined on it.

`data` is an **array** containing **many** objects with `name` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const api_url = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/41P1_UhSI'  
async function getAPI() {   
  await fetch(api_url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      data.map(it => 
      console.log(it.name))
    }); 
} 
getAPI();
```